# What happens to answers on duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion

If a question is marked as a duplicate for another question, what happens to the answers for the duplicate question?  Are they merged with the original?  Does the duplicate question remain in the system?

If no to both these (the are not merged, and the duplicated question is to be deleted), then if an answer for the duplicate question applies equally to the original question as well, should the person who wrote the answer for the duplicate question then respond to the original question as well with the same answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question marked "*duplicate*" is closed and the link to the other duplicate is added on top.  The questions and their answers remain unchanged.

"*Merge*" requires an additional action which is done by moderators.  I haven't done it myself (yet), so I don't have first hand experience.  [Here's an SE blog post about merging.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/)
Merging is seldom done on EE.SE (don't know if there is a rationale against doing it).

Comment: This is correct. There isn't an automatic moderator notification of a duplicate questions (and merge opportunities). If there is a good answer on a duplicate question, then you can flag that for moderator attention.